# Android get available codecs for video recording

Tags: android, android-camera, galaxy, mediarecorder

My app have to record video with resolution & codec parameters being selected by user.

Here is my code to get available video resolutions:

```
Camera camera=Camera.open();
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
```

But how to get available video codecs for current Android device?
I know about https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.html Android constants, but for example Galaxy S3 fails with my app if set videoencoder to H.263. So how to check available codecs at each device?

Comment: You have probably sorted this out by now but why not set to default? Defines the video encoding. These constants are used with setVideoEncoder(int).
0 will give you the default.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.html#DEFAULT